# Need query to get data as per below

Tags: sql, sql-server

Input Table is

| Target | Agent | RankA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15000 | A | null |
| 15000 | A | null |
| 14500 | A | null |

required output is

| Target | Agent | RankA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15000 | A | 1 |
| 15000 | A | 1 |
| 14500 | A | 3 |

as first record is 15000, so its rank is 1
as second record is 15000, so its rank is also 1
as third record is 14500, so its rank is also 3 and not 2 because even though first two records have same record, the count is now 2 so new rank will be 3 for third record

need query for the same..

here is script for data preparation

```sql
SELECT 15000 TARGET,
       '' AS AGENT,
       NULL RANKA
INTO #TABLEA;  

INSERT INTO #TABLEA
VALUES (1400, 'B', NULL);
```

Comment: what is the last column there 33, 33, 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `rank()` to get the rank, and rank/count to get Percentile

```
with cte as (
  select Target, Agent, rank() over (partition by Agent order by Target desc) as Ranka
  from TableA
)
select Target, Agent, cast(Ranka as float)/CAST(count(*) over (partition by Agent) AS FLOAT)*100 as Percentile
from cte
```

Or this if you dont need Percentile :

```
select Target, Agent, rank() over (partition by Agent order by Target desc) as Ranka
from TableA
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uMsAb2Al)